# python parse string to exact float

Tags: python

Seen some other questions but none have answered this particular case

```
val = "0.000"
print val
0.000
f = float(val)
print f
0.0
```

How can I keep these as floats but force them to be the exact value of `0.000`?

Comment: Isn't `0.0` same as `0.0000`? Some other example would have been better

Comment: No, 0.000 represents 0 down to 10^-4

Comment: @Badmiral but `0.0 == 0.0000 = True`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html "The decimal module incorporates a notion of significant places"

Comment: @Badmiral: `0.0` is 0 down to the maximum precision.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if OP is doing for example physics stuff, there's a difference between 0.0 and 0.00

Comment: @Jasper: sure, but when using `float` that is what you get. NPE has this covered.

Answer (score 4):

The `float` values `0.0` and `0.000` are indistinguishable from one another: they are represented by exactly the same bit pattern.

You'd have to use a different data type -- such as a string or [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) -- if you want to preserve the zeroes:

```
In [7]: from decimal import Decimal

In [8]: d1 = Decimal("0.0")

In [9]: d2 = Decimal("0.000")

In [10]: str(d1)
Out[10]: '0.0'

In [11]: str(d2)
Out[11]: '0.000'
```